# Cypress and Google sign in

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

Using Cypress and page requires sign in with Google. I don't want to use Google cloud Using Cypress and page requires sign in with Google. I don't want to use Google cloud, I can log in manually, and how to avoid the sign-in page and land home page directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about a pre-production environment, you should get rid of such login schemes, because it requires some work to get round them in testing tools. Make your pre-production environments accessible only from your VPN, that should suffice.

If, from whatever, reason you really need to keep these authentication schemes on, then read about authentication on Cypress site [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/auth0-authentication). There is a chapter about [Google](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/google-authentication) as well. Generally speaking, you want to avoid authentication via UI, so all these tutorials on Cypress page authenticate via an API.

Comment: Preferred to add an option to log-in via email and password as well as saving google sign-in, thank you